# Need to dynamically create ViewController objects from a tableView selection in iOS

Tags: ios, for-loop, uiviewcontroller, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `UIViewController` in my iOS application that displays a table that is derived from an `NSMutableArray`.  The cells in this table each refer to a unique `UIViewController` that is called when the user makes a selection.  What I am trying to do in my "didSelectRowAtIndexPath:" method is to dynamically create the `UIViewController` via an `NSMutableDictionary` that contains keys that match the values in the `NSMutableArray` that the table is built from, as well as values that contain the corresponding Class names for the respective `UIViewController` that needs to be called.  Because the list is rather long, I figure I need to do this using a for loop, but I am a bit confused as to how to do it.  My `NSMutableDictionary` looks like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:@"aViewController" forKey:@"SelectionA"];
    [dict setObject:@"bViewController" forKey:@"SelectionB"];
    [dict setObject:@"cViewController" forKey:@"SelectionC"];
```

and my NSMutableArray that is the basis for my TableView looks like this:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"SelectionA", @"SelectionB", @"SelectionC",...,nil];
```

How would I obtain a reference to the value inside the cell, and then construct a for loop that would dynamically create the correct viewController that corresponds to the selection made by the user from the tableView, and then take the user to that viewController via the navigationController?

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Comment: ad "The cells in this table each refer to a unique ViewController ", why the hell? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes I am.  This is not a list of identical items that can share a single viewController.  Each selection has different data that needs to be displayed.  The alternative would to have a single viewController, but in that viewController's "viewDidLoad" method, I would have a huge list of if/else statements (or switch/case statements) that would build the viewController according to the selection.

Comment: Ok, then it dpends what you want to display If the is reraly looking different, like I showd below, a road mao view, a bitmap view,. a  text view, the various differnt view Controller is ok. It´s then your decisiion to go wiether with differnet view controller, or to use one conmtroller with different sub views, you can hide, depending on the cell data.  I will update my code for your case. too

Comment: Don't you have those switch/case statements somewhere anyway?

Comment: Where do you create the ViewControllers?

Comment: I plan to create the appropriate viewControllers in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.  The viewControllers exist, but the issue is about creating the correct reference dynamically and then sending the user to the right one.

Comment: If you are trying to cache all viewControllers to increase speed you will propably fail, because ios is very limited in memory. After ~5 Controllers (depending on content) your app might even crash, because it can't keep them all around. You will have to dump the viewControllers somehow/sometime. Rethink how you could keep track of the data, not the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **really need** a view controller for each cell, there's no need to use a dictionary to look them up.  Since selection will be by index path, an array is a better choice.

Create a custom object that has two properties: the name you want to display in the cell and a pointer to the view controller you want to push when it's selected.  Load `myArray` with these objects instead of strings.  When you are populating a cell, select the object that matches the row and use its name.  When a cell is tapped, select the object that matches the row and push its controller.

(But, as others have said, if you can use the same controller and only change the data, that's the way to go!)

Comment: Your solution makes sense, but should I not have a property in the object that holds the ViewController class name in order to dynamically create the ViewController?

Comment: I'm assuming that there must be a one-to-one match between cell row numbers and controllers.  In that case, I'd cache the actual controller.  I don't believe they are large objects unless they have all their views loaded...and you can dynamically load/unload views if memory profiling shows that you need that optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Its not a good idea to create many ViewControllers, you should create one ViewController,
and pass the value of they tableCell to it. In other words, you change the data modell of the ViewController, by selecting the cell. But you will present the Same ViewController.

Only in the case that your cells coreesponmd to different types (e.g one cell a road mao, another a text value) , you have to call different ViewControllers.

If you realy need different view contollers, then get the type you want to dispaly from the cell data

in `didSelectCellRowAtIndexPath`

```
myAppDelegate *appDelegate = 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

UIViewController *viewControllerToDisplay;
switch (selection.type) {
  case MapType:  
      viewControllerToDisplay = appDelegate.mapViewController;
  case Picture:
      viewControllerToDisplay = appDelegate.pictureViewController;

}
```

now push viewControllerToDisplay to navigaton Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,
If you know the name of class then store all the classes name in array with dictionary having key ClassName and Xib. I prefer plist to store names but you can use other way also.

And at **didselect** of *table or picker* place the code like this,

```
Class classobject = NSClassFromString([[ClassArray   objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"ClassName"]);

id object = [[classobject alloc] initWithNibName:[[ClassArray objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"Xib"] bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:object animated:YES];
```

First line will convert your string to class.
Now as we have a benefit that id can hold any object so creat the object using id. And finally  you have a custom class object you can do whatever you want to do with it,here for just a demo I did navigation.